# How to replace a word in html only if some conditions are met with regex

Tags: html, node.js, regex

I try to replace every occurrence of a word in a text (which is a html file) and everything around until we meet a `"` or a `'` or a `(` for behind or a `)` for forward with a regex using nodejs.

My problem is that when I have two words to replace let's say `3.png` and `13.png`, `13.png` is being replaced too by matching `3.png` and when I come to replace `13.png` in my text it's not there because it was already replaced when matching previous `3.png`.

My ideal solution would be :

`if` matched pattern contains a `/`

`then` it must exact match after `/` and replace everything around (slash included) until we meet one of these characters (excluded) `"` or a `'` or a `(` for behind or a `)`

`else` exact match between `""` or `''` or `()`

---

You can find here a [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/gF8ZWE/2)

Currently I'm sorting my words to search like so:

```
  imgjson.sort((a, b) => b.name.length - a.name.length);
```

in order to replace the longest words first which solves my problem because we replace `13.png` first then `3.png` but I would like to know if this can be done with js regex?

Thanks a lot for your reply and time!

Comment: You can surround your smaller numbers like `3` with `\b3\b` to avoid it getting matched with `13.png` but then `3.png` should not be preceded by any word character.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi thanks for reply! that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

As @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi told use `\b`.

If you want to be more accurate and informed about regex, you can use https://regex101.com/.
In right-bottom corner you can find all special characters and functions of regex you may be need to use.